# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality Proof Question

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to follow proof 2 of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality

I've gotten to the point where they let $\mathbf {u} ={\frac {\langle \mathbf {u} ,\mathbf {v} \rangle }{\langle \mathbf {v} ,\mathbf {v} \rangle }}\mathbf {v} +\mathbf {z}$. Then they say this gives $ \|\mathbf {u} \|^{2}=\left|{\frac {\langle \mathbf {u} ,\mathbf {v} \rangle }{\langle \mathbf {v} ,\mathbf {v} \rangle }}\right|^{2}\|\mathbf {v} \|^{2}+\|\mathbf {z} \|^{2}$

How do they get this equivalence? I started by taking the norm of both sides, and and get $\|\mathbf{u}\| = ||{\frac {\langle \mathbf {u} ,\mathbf {v} \rangle }{\langle \mathbf {v} ,\mathbf {v} \rangle }}\mathbf {v} \|+\|\mathbf {z} \|$. How do you go further from here?

Really, I'm very confused as to how you can start with norms and ever end up with an absolute value?

Comment: Note that $x^2=|x|^2$ since $x^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField But x can be complex, so this isn't true?

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are orthogonal, then
$$\begin{align*}
\lVert \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\rVert^2 &= \langle \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\rangle\\
&= \langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle + \langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle + \langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}\rangle + \langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}\rangle\\
&= \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert^2 + \lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert^2.
\end{align*}$$
This is the "generalized Pythagorean Theorem" (think about vectors $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{y}$, and $\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}$ on the plane, forming a triangle).

In your expression, $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{z}$ have been shown to be orthogonal to each other, hence so are $\alpha\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{z}$ for any scalar $\alpha$. The expression now follows.

Comment: Yes I understand that, thanks! If we take the square of $(|| \frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}‖+‖‖)$, then we get $|| \frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}‖^2+‖‖^2$. How is $||\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}‖^2$ equal to $‖ \frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}‖   ‖^2‖$?

Comment: Sorry, meant to ask how is $||\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}‖^2$ equal to $| \frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩} | ‖^2‖$?. Particularly the swapping of the norm for the absolute value makes no sense to me.

Comment: @lightnesscaster for any norm and scalar $\lambda$ you have $||\lambda v|| = |\lambda| ||v||$. This is a basic property of norms.

Comment: @lightnesscaster: We do not, repeat, **not**, "take the square of $(\lVert \alpha\mathbf{v}\rVert + \lVert\mathbf{z}\rVert)$". We don't. That's the whole point of the equations above. We are taking the squared norm of the sum, not the square of the sums of the norms. And as noted, for any vector $\mathbf{x}$ and any scalar $\alpha$, you always have $\lVert \alpha\mathbf{x}\rVert = |\alpha|\,\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Ah of course you're right thanks!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm not really sure what you're saying (or maybe I didn't write my comments clearly), but I think I understand now! So starting with  =$\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}$+, first you take the norm of both sides of the equation. Then, you get |||| = ||$\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}$+|| = ||$\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}$||+||z||+$\sqrt{<\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩},z>}$. $\sqrt{<\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩},z>}$ = 0 because they're orthogonal, so we get |||| = ||$\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}$||+||z||. Now we square both sides and get $||||^2$ = $||\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}||^2+||z||^2$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, I made a mistake and it will only let me edit for 5 minutes for some reason. I meant to say that after we have ||$\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}$||+||z||, we know we get |$\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}$||+||z|| = |$\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}|$||||+||z|, as pointed out. |Now we square both sides and get $||||^2$ = $|\frac{⟨,⟩}{⟨,⟩}|^2 ||||^2+||z||^2$ (since v and z are orthogonal). This is the expression we were trying to get all along! Is this what you meant?

Comment: @lightnesscaster: No, you are still not actually reading what I wrote. You start from $\mathbf{u}=\alpha\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{z}$. You take **the norm squared on both sides**, to get $\lVert\mathbf{u}\rVert^2 = \lVert \alpha\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{z}\rVert^2$. Then you use the Pythagorean Theorem to separate the right hand side. You don’t just take the norm, then square. Your equation for the norm is **wrong**, and if you square that you do **not** get what you claim you get.

Comment: @lightnesscaster: so let me repeat it for the **fourth** time. You do not take the norms, then square. You take the norm-squared **first**.